# Why does a material created in Substance Alchemist look completely different when imported to Blender?

Tags: materials, import

[image: screenshot of Substance Alchemist]

[image: screenshot of Blender]

I created a material in Substance Alchemist and even materialized but when set up in Blender it looks very different even when I adjust the height values. Is my node setup incorrect?

Comment: Your setup looks fine to me, I can't really tell how its different from substance since I don't know what the substance preview looked like. Are you using the displacement modifier?

Comment: oh sorry about that i thought i added the second photo

Answer (score 3):

This quick PBR material setup reference may help you. It's based on Allegorithmic Substance textures.

[image: Quick PBR material setup reference]

Comment: Why is bump better than normals?

Comment: Mesh displacement doesn't work with normal map information. Normal maps simulate surface displacement/structure but doesn't change the mesh vertex positions.